# Share AMI with a user across of different AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS supports to share AMI or Snapshot across account by just modifying the permissions.
To share AMI we need to enter Target Account ID, then it will be shared with Target Account.
I want to share that AMI with a particular user in the target account.
is it possible?
if yes, then what are the steps required?
TIA :)

Comment: add a deny policy to all IAM users for that particular AMI, except that 1 user.

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible in the source account to restrict access to a specific user in the target account.

In general, cross-account sharing is about creating trust from one account to the root user of the other account.

This trust allows the root user of the target account to delegate access to resources (via IAM policies). In this case the resource is the AMI.

So, if you want to restrict access to that AMI in the target account to a particular user then you need to:

1. Share the AMI as you mentioned from the source account to the target account (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html)
2. Create an IAM policy in the target account to allow access to AMIs
3. Attach that IAM policy to the user/group/role.

Something like the following attached to the user/group/role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AccessImages",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:CopyImage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```